# Old anime where two alien brothers seek revenge for their father, who was killed by the heroes

Tags: story-identification, anime

I have a fragmentary memory of an anime episode I watched as a young kid (circa 1983). One scene has stuck with me ever since and I'd love to know what the show was so I can find it again. Here's what I remember:

- probably Japanese & dubbed into English
- There are two alien antagonists, who are brothers
- Their father is killed by the good guys
- After the funeral, the brothers get into their respective spaceships (which, IIRC, have helicopter-style rotors on top) and set out for revenge on the heroes

Does this ring any bells?

EDIT: I think this is in the "Star Blazers"/"Battle of the Planets"/"Force Five" genre somewhere. Could even be one of those, for all I know.

## Further details, such as they are

A couple of other fragments:

- This aired in the northeastern US.
- The guys in the helicopter spaceships were humanoid but lumpish.
- The funeral scene involved an open casket, with alien flowers or something stuffed all around the corpse.

To be clear, this wasn't a show I watched regularly, or I'd remember much more. I was at a friend's house, this show was on, we watched part of it and then went to do something else. Thus the scarcity of useful details.

Comment: That's pretty vague. Don't you remember anything else? Like what did the good guys looked like? What did the bad guys look like? In what language and what region did you watch it? Almost anything is helpful at this point.

Comment: Believe me, I know it's not much to go on. Just dredged up a little more; for what it's worth.

Comment: What did the aliens look like?